# How to start SIP Client Twinkle as service?

Tags: bash

my apologies upfront for anything that i miss, it is my first question.

I was trying to setup my raspberry as sip client.
This sipclient would trigger a bash script to trigger the gpios.
finally this would be the interface for a door latch opener.

setting up the sip client works just fine.
triggering works also fine (after figuring out that every script has to have #!/bin/bash as header!)
going through a whitelist... everything perfect.

execpt:
i was not able to manage to start twinkle as "service" on start up.

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --user pi --pidfile /var/run/twinkle.pid --make-pidfile --background --exec /usr/bin/twinkle -- -c
```

did not do the job.

```
export DISPLAY=:1
twinkle -c
```

works only interactively.

with xvfb installed.

```
/usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -screen 0 640x480x24 -ac +extension GLX +render -noreset
```

but twinkle seems to stop immediately when parent process is destroyed.

i also tried linphone... but could not figure out how to trigger my script :-(

another tool i tried was asterisk, but would not install on my raspberry.
after a long install process it just stopped. thats why i set it asside. i dont have the results anymore. sorry for that.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i went a different route:
doorpi is the tool that gave me all the possibilities that i needed.

- doorpi is running in background (as service)
- doorpi is able to start a sip client and with that receive calls
- doorpi can use the gpios